# Combine multiple array into string PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Let's say i have the following:

```
Germany, Berlin
France, Paris
England, London
Spain, Madrid
```

What i'm trying to do is to combine those words so i can get the following:

```
Germany-Berlin,France-Paris,England-London,Spain-Madrid
```

as a continuous string.

My problem is that are some cases when i have more rows than one so i want to combine all of them into a string so i can insert the whole string into a mysql field.

Everything i try gets me to the point that i have only the last string inserted into the mysql field, in this case being Spain-Madrid.I'm tring to merge Germany with Berlin by using a - between them and after that to combine this string with the rest of the strings.
In the end i want to have inserted into the mysql field something like this:

```
Germany-Berlin,France-Paris,England-London,Spain-Madrid
```

Comment: `explode()` + `str_replace()` + `implode()` = voila :-)

Comment: Are the countries you listed strings in an array?

Comment: @CoDEmanX yes they are

Comment: For me it's not simple that's why i'm looking for help. Everything i try i get only the last string inserted into the mysql field instead of the whole string.

Comment: MySQL doesn't complain if you insert the original string with newlines and everything, just quote it properly. Is there any reason why you want to transform that string? Will you have to re-transform it back to the original form? how about using a standard format so you can easily decode it like JSON?

Comment: @ggioffreda - Unless the attempt to manipulate the string only leaves the last part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$str = "
Germany, Berlin
France, Paris
England, London
Spain, Madrid
";

$str = explode("\r\n", trim($str));

for ($i = 0, $l = count($str); $i < $l; $i++) {
    $str[$i] = str_replace(', ', '-', $str[$i]);
}

$str = implode(',', $str);

echo $str;

?>
```

http://codepad.org/df1UUOvi

The reason it's not as simple as it appears is that there's two groups, with a swap:

**Outer Group**

```
Germany, Berlin
```

**Inner Group**

```
Germany
Berlin
```

You have to work on each group separately, with the `,` being swapped out of the outer group to separate the inner group. Hence, unless someone does something clever, you have to split the outer groups apart, iterate and replace the `,` with `-` in the inner group, then re-join with the separating `,`.

**Note**

One-liner:

```
$str = implode(',', explode("\r\n", str_replace(', ', '-', trim($str))));
```

http://codepad.org/p2e3ozMv

Comment: it won't help me cause the content in the $str is made by a foreach that combines country with capital city.

Comment: You posted a value that appears to be in a string. Using what you provided, I've solved that problem. Unless you provide more information in your question, it's going to be difficult to understand what you mean. Please provide what creates the value you provided, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As a single-liner:

```
$arr = array(
    "Germany, Berlin",
    "France, Paris",
    "England, London",
    "Spain, Madrid"
);

array_walk($arr, function(&$s){$s = str_replace(", ", "-", $s);});

echo(implode(",", $arr));
```

Output: `Germany-Berlin,France-Paris,England-London,Spain-Madrid`